# Что считается началом присоединительного оборота?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, присоединительный

> Она часто ездила за границу и, в частности, в Берлин.

В данном случае, как я понимаю, есть однородный ряд: за границу, в Берлин, между ними вводное слово.
Можно ли это предложение было оформить как присоединительный оборот?

> Она часто ездила за границу, и в частности в Берлин.

Нужно было бы во второй фразе выделять "в частности" двумя запятыми как вводное слово, стоящее в середине присоединительного оборота, или же это положение все еще считалось "начальным" для вводного слова (тогда не нужны знаки)?

Comment: Во втором примере И лишнее.

Comment: А первое предложение корректно?

Comment: Не заметил, тоже нет, потому что у И значение "и ещё"/"плюс". Здесь же не частица, а союз.

Comment: Может ли вообще "и" в такой позиции быть связующим элементом между однородными, если стоит рядом с "в частности"?

Comment: Не может. И вводит новый элемент, а "в частности" относится к предыдущему.

Comment: Вот такая структура должна быть: *Она часто ездила за границу, в частности в Берлин, и в столицу.* Но здесь стилистический недочёт: заграница делится на страны, а не на города, поэтому Берлин желательно заменить на Германию.

Comment: Это только "в частности" касается или каких-то других присоединительных слов тоже?:

Comment: Просто в НКРЯ много примеров, где идет однородны член, потом "и", в частности, однородный член. Они все неверные?

Comment: Если "в частности" после И, то оно не присоединительное и у него значение "особенно". В вашем примере так не получается, потому что при изъятии выходит это: *Она часто ездила за границу и в Берлин.*

Comment: Когда говорил, что не может, имел в виду присоединительное "в частности".

Comment: Приведите пример,пожалуйста, где в "частности" в роли вводного стоит после "и", присоединяя однородный член, и этот пример правильный.

Comment: Пример из справочника: *И вот он лежит себе на кровати и думает разные отчаянные мысли — о
том, о сем и, в частности, о вздорности любовных порывов* (М.Зощенко).

Comment: То есть "присоединительное в частности" должно всегда указывать на узость понятия?

Comment: Да, без этого никак. Само слово "частность" (от "частный") это подразумевает.

Comment: Предположим, что все-таки нашелся пример, где "и" стоит до присоединительного " в частности", считается ли, что "в частности" находится в середине обособленного оборота? Или все-таки это начало?

Comment: Нет, это не начало, потому что в начале союз.

Comment: По правилу тогда ведь оно должно выделяться с двух сторон запятыми.

Comment: Ну да, так и надо.

Comment: На сайте нашел одном. Здравствуйте, правильно ли расставлены запятые? Поддерживаем мероприятия, направленные на развитие кластерной политики, и в частности инновационных территориальных кластеров.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Comment: Запятых нет. Почему?

Comment: Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания у оборота в частности в предложении? Необходимо систематизировать результаты научных, и в частности экономических, исследований по данному вопросу. Знаки препинания расставлены верно.

Comment: Они нужны. Ладно, скажу тогда, в чём дело. Само это правило существует для устранения двусмысленности, а если вводное слово после союза, то никакой двусмысленности быть не может. По этой логике запятая ставится, если оборот в скобках. Но в правилах не сказано о случаях с союзами. Справочная служба, видимо, решила не перегружать предложение запятыми.

Comment: Кстати, раз уж я этот пример тут уже привел, скажете мне, почему в предложении выделили присоединение запятыми, а не однородные члены: "Поддерживаем мероприятия, направленные на развитие кластерной политики, и в частности инновационных территориальных кластеров"?

Comment: По идее же такая мысль: направленные на развитие кластерной политики и, в частности, на развитие инновационных территориальных кластеров.

Comment: Структура не очень. Дело в том, что политика предполагает действие, а не предмет. Они включают эти кластеры в кластерную политику, но это не совсем правильно, хотя в речи людей можно и не такое услышать. Розенталь рассказывал про свои удивительные находки в материалах прессы.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!